# uasort Issues - Maximum Value to output first

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So if I had 2 columns in a object

A -> values are 10 8 6 4

B -> values are 9 7 5 3

I want to merge B into A with 9 below 10, 7 below 8 etc.

```
uasort($TopConsumers,array('Utilities','orderconsumers'));
public static function orderConsumers($TopConsumers)
{
    $a = $TopConsumers->outTotal;
    $b = $TopConsumers->inTotal;
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : +1;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting function needs to have $a and $b as arguments to it. Not the array itself.

```
public static function orderConsumers($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->outTotal == $b->inTotal) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->outTotal > $b-inTotal) ? -1 : +1;
}
```

That said it seems a little odd to sort by two columns. I'm not sure this is going to give you what you're looking for. Normally you'd compare the same column name in a user sort function like that.

Comment: Well what im doing is I have two collumns , one for inbound traffic and one for outbound traffic. I need to display on the webpage which one is higher. This is notify our staff that they are using a TON of outbound or inbound traffic. And we would liek them to be in order. Hope that gives some insight.

Comment: public static function OrderC($a,$b)
{
if ($a->inTotal == $b->outTotal) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->inTotal > $b->outTotal) ? -1 : +1;

} 
*** 7,541.11
*** 6,901.45
*** 7,070.75
***10,037.45

Didnt work :(-(

Comment: I get what you're saying but think of it this way: $a and $b are different rows in your data set. You're comparing outbound to inbound on two different rows, not the same row. I just did a little test and this will definitely not give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry I must have confused you. 

Here is a sample of my data 

TopConsumers

Column->inTotal: 1000 , 2000 ,3000

Column->OutTotal 5000, 1000, 8000

It should display 8000 (out), 5000(out), 2000(in).

Answer (score 3):

You need to merge the arrays first, then sort them.

```
$merged = array_merge($TopConsumers->outTotal, $TopConsumers->inTotal);
sort($merged);
```

Comment: I need them to only display one of the values , sorry forgot to specify

Comment: +1: For not using `uasort()` @Luke: Sorry, what does that mean? No duplicates? --> `array_unique()`

Comment: Sorry i asked the wrong question without enough information. My fault, Thank you for you help though!